Right understanding and meaning of this particular reservation
following is a conversation I had with a guy sometime ago. As not a native speaker, I wants badly to know correct meaning of the messages I recieve so I decided to write down here again with a question.
My first message:

hey,
quite a while since our last talk.
Looks like Scramble is no longer active nowadays but glad there is this website that hopefully will grow stronger soon.
to expand myself a little - apparently the F-35A is no longer active as much as before due to another generation of her that will probably fly soon in slightly different form (a larger fuselage maybe?). I guess she acts as a test platform to the newer generation of her.
Apparently, actually it seems the 90's Joint Strike Fighter (JSF) program which consumed much of the Budget and you mentioned at one point, was a combination of three different platforms from one overarching program but each individually distinct. Apparently, different missions but one common program. One platform was CTOL, another was STOVL and the third was a joint asset CV. Generally relation similar to F-111B/EF-111A and F-111A Aardvark.
The F-35C is closely related to her predecessor that was retired already and the other platform is still flying, apparently. No hard data about the third platform though (semi-operational maybe?) beside it being flying from aircraft carriers.
Do you agree with this interpretations?
cheers*

A reply I received:

More or less, yes. There have been two distinct platforms after the F-16 according to the rumor mill, with Lockheed currently working on the so called sixth-generation fighter.

Is it clear and without a doubt (from a context of the conversation, and messages presented) that the guy answering that "there have been two distinct platforms after the F-16" referring to the timeframe I asked - so the 90's and JSF program, or may it be an indication, as well, to the general timeframe lasting from the time of when F-16 entered production to the present time - and we cannot really say from the context and provided data?

Edited. Now you should be able to answer that.

I presume you're asking about the scope of the word after. It depends on context. I arrived at the party after John.  This presumably means after John arrived, but we can easily create a sentence "I arrived after John left. As a person who knows nothing about the subject, I can tell you the time marker used for comparison is the F-16, but I can't say anything more precise.

Yep, exactly this is what made the biggest problem to me, trying to understand it on my own. If to believe that it was the case here, then, "two distinct platforms" would be a comparision to the F-16, so not the whole time period from that time to present but rather strictly after the F-16, are you agree?

Well it's obviously after the F-16, but that's my point. I don't know anything more about the details of that comparison. "After the F-16 was introduced"? "After the F-16 became obsolete"? "After the F-16 was painted red"?

Before going further, you had a conversation not  'sometime' but 'some time' ago. Does that work for you?
Rather than 'As not a native speaker…' use either 'As a non-native speaker' or 'not being a a native speaker… Does that work for you?
More…

Further… why not before Posting anything like 'I wants badly to know correct meaning of the messages I recieve so I decided to write down here again with a question…' use your spelling and grammar checkers?
More…

Further… why use 'I wants badly to know correct meaning of the messages I recieve so I decided to write down here again with a question…'
Why not use 'I badly want to know the correct meaning of the messages I receive/(have received)…'?
More…

Further…
Since it doesn't work in English, what did 'I decided to write down here again with a question…' mean in your own language?
More…

Further… what could any interpretation mean by '…this particular reservation…'?
More…

Further… how would it hurt to drop all the aircraft specifications and such, and instead Ask about English?

OP has enquired about the time frame in the message:

More or less, yes. There have been two distinct platforms after the F-16 according to the rumor mill, with Lockheed currently working on the so called sixth-generation fighter.

Your friend has clearly mentioned the time frame as (the development) after F16.
I think your confusion is that you named and calculated three platforms while he corrected you and said that there had been only "two distinct platforms".
Here is the explanation what your friend meant:
I checked and found that the platforms you mentioned were variants of the same F-35 platform.
The two distinct platforms after F16 are: F22 and F35 (variants F-35A, F-35B and F-35C.)

Source Wikipedia:

F-22 Raptor
F-35 (which includes F-35A, F-35B and F-35C variants)
In aerospace, a "platform" can refer to a shared design, architecture, or core system. The F-35A, F-35B, and F-35C are considered variants of the same platform :
'1. F-35A (CTOL): Conventional take-off and landing, for USAF.
'2. F-35B (STOVL): Short take-off and vertical landing, for USMC.
'3. F-35C (CV): Carrier variant, with modifications for naval operations.



Thank you, James. Well, that could solve that riddle I guess but I enquired the time frame in my message as referring strictly to the 90's (this is the only timeframe I referred to) and that's why its so confusing to me - F-35 wasn't around in the 90's but came later. Do you think we can safly assume that my friend answering that there were two distinct platforms meant about the scope ranging from all the years after F16 to present day? That is what makes me think as I never mentioned about the 2000's. the 2010's etc.

@Noone_new I have to depend on google to get my information as I am not aware how things happened at Lockheed. Google says it was 1978, when F16 was developed/ put into action. Yes it is the years ranging after that. But Lockheed isn't changing the platform every year. Only two platforms have been introduced after that. You can consider the time after 1990s to the present. (F36 is not a separate platform). I think work is going on three platforms) F-21
A The F-21 Block 70 i
F-35 Lightning II
F-16 Fighting Falcon

Thanks, James. I think you meant F-22 instead of F-21, correct? I just tend to think of why he decided to tell full history ranging from the 70's to present instead of keeping the timeframe rules for the 90's only, as this is the timeframe I specifically asked him about. I guess we can be sure that due to the fact he choose to use "there have been two distinct platforms after F-16" so Present Perfect it undoubtly means he refers to all timeframe ranging from the 70's up to present day, ,are you agree? (Asking about english rules of writing now)

@Noone_new Yes Present Perfect is used for life experience. "I have been to Thailand twice. (until now).

As for the "distinct platforms" phrase, is it means two totally different, and separate platforms, like F-22 and F-35? I guess from your post now, that both things mentioned are nowhere near to be a common thing but they are different, unconnected to each other likely both with different mission goal and destiny. If that's true then F-35A can't be 'distinct' from F-35B, as they originate from the same platform and are the same basic platform but all are a part of the same lineage/family. The distinct platform in its true meaning would be, like you said, F-22 and F-35. Could you extend on that?

@Noone_new As I understand what you mentioned as 3 platforms are only one platform (3 variants F-35A F-35B and F-35C). The second platform is for F22. Lockheed don't change the platform often but releases new variants on the same platform. It is kept secret which new platforms they are developing. From Google I found that F22 is another platform.

No, a sentence starting There have been… cannot be referring to a period that is now completely past (which the 1990s is). For that meaning, the sentence would have to begin There were…
The present-perfect version implies “from then (some mutually understood moment) up through now.” In the case you present, the moment is one related to the F-16 program. Exactly which moment (initiation, low-rate initial production, retirement from service by some user, etc.) is unclear from the passage you quote here.

While I agree with your conclusion, I don't agree with the statement that present perfect always includes the present. "There have been US Presidents who were assassinated." is fine.

@Barmar, what your sentence means is that in all of U.S history so far there have been presidents who were assassinated. I don't know what you mean by your assessment that your sentence "is fine." I certainly don't dispute its acceptability.

Now I see what you're saying. It doesn't exclude the present like simple past does.

I suggest that in cases as described in this Question, there is no useful difference. Rather, in the context of the Question, 'There have been…' and 'There were…' are interchangeable.
There are circumstances in which they differ importantly, but not here.
